# Javascript React Switch Case with dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, switch-statement, key

```
const changeSelectValue = (state, action) => {
switch (action.id) {
    case 'myFirstKey':
        updatedState = {
            ...state,
            myFirstKey: action.value
        }
    case 'mySecondKey':
        updatedState = {
            ...state,
            mySecondKey: action.value
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}}
```

I can not really find a solution or don't know how to search for it, so maybe you can help. This switch case updates the key inside the state by the action.id

Since I have a lot of different keys to handle, this switch case becomes extremely long, there must be a way to make this way simpler, but I can not get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a switch if it's dynamic.

```
const changeSelectValue = (state, action) => {
  updatedState = {
    ...state,
    [action.id]: action.value
  }
}
```

Comment: That feeling when your code goes from 600 lines to 6 ;;;;;;;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing the brakets all this time :)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try:

```
const changeSelectValue = (state, action) => {
   let updatedState = {...state}
   updatedState[action.id] = action.value
   return updatedState
}
```